# How to pass python variable string to shell command

Tags: python-3.x, variables, environment-variables, global-variables

I have some environment variables that are set inside my python script and I would like to pass them inside my shell command.
Is this the correct approach?

```
import os    

    #Set environment variable
    os.environ['VERISON'] = '1.30'

    #Get environment variable
    worker_version = os.environ.get('VERSION')

    
    #Shell command

    build_worker = Popen("cd /home/ubuntu/directory && docker build -t Test:$VERSION -f docker/Dockerfile.Test .", shell=True)
    build_worker.wait()
```

$VERSION should be set to '1.30' but isn't working

Comment: There's a typo: `VERISON` rather than `VERSION`

Comment: As a side-note, if the variables are only relevant to this subprocess rather than the main process, it may be neater to pass them to `Popen` in the `env` parameter; however, either way should work

Comment: While @JiříBaum solved your problem I will also point out you could have solved your problem by replacing the `Popen` command with something like `env` to show the actual env vars available to the external shell command(s). Which might have caused you to recognize the env var you expected was not set.